# 1D ifft of array created with rfft2 along trimmed axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, fft

I'm having a problem trying to make a partial inverse transform (synthesis along one dimension) of an array created with `rfft2` (and, of course, later filtered).

The thing is that I work with real input for the whole program and it makes sense then to go from real to spectral (Fourier) domain using `rfft2` to exploit this symmetry (I do quite a lot of transforms in this program). This generates from a `(nx,ny)` matrix of real numbers a `(nx,ny//2-1)` (the last number has a +1 if ny is odd, but you get the point). I'll name this process going from `(x,y)` domain to `(kx,ky)` domain. I can revert this process using `irfft2` and get back my real data.

However at a single point in my algorithm, I must manipulate data in an intermediate domain: `(kx,y)`. In this domain, I don't know if the coefficients (which are still complex) hold some symmetry relation but I strongly suspect they must verify that coefficients at `(kx,y)` and `(-kx,y)` are conjugates of each other.

I thought of manually creating an array of (nx,ny) complex numbers in (kx,ky) domain (explicitly using the symmetries), and simply using `ifft` along the last (`y`) axis. However this get quite nasty to read and IMHO quite error prone, not to mention efficiency which I could resign for this single step.

The actual question is, can I efficiently use `numpy` to compute the coefficients for the expansion at this mixed domain?

Cheers,

Comment: Why you want to create this `(kx, y)`? It sounds so weird

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The complete answer would be rather cumbersome, but long story short I have to match a function which admits an expansion in Fourier series in x direction and hyperbolic trigonometric functions in y direction (solution to Laplace's equation) with a function that has a Fourier expansion in both directions but in an y-extended domain. Then the coefficients for the sin,sinh expansion can be obtained from the (kx,y) expansion of the doubly periodic function.

Comment: In principle you can do that. If you post part of your code that relevant, we might be able to help

Comment: I'll post a snippet later with the proper math to make the problem clear. For the time being I'm using `rfft(irfft2(data, s=size), axis=0)` to accomplish what I need. Extremely inefficient, but allows me to keep developing the rest of the algorithm and check if the underlying idea actually works before being stalled due to optimizing prematurely. In the meantime I'll keep thinking about this and I'll be providing the math and the snippet in the upcoming days.